# Documentation tools for hardware project

Tags: documentation

## Background

There is a hardware project going on. A hardware accelerator has been being developed by a team of students but there is no general documentation.
There are `README`s here and there, some `docx`s and *in-code* (`Verilog`, `C` and `Lua`) comments, but nothing else. The code is written with `Vim`, versioned with `Git` and `Markdown` is our friend, even if we are not on `Github` (yet).
Since this “thing” is growing, I feel the necessity of writing down something (user manual? developer notes?) but I don't know where to start.

## Question

When someone feels the urge of documenting his project, where does it start?
More specifically, what are the *generally accepted* criteria to do it and what are the *best tools*?

### My hypothetical answer

We quite clearly need both a *developer* and *user* manual. One with details of the algorithmic solutions, the other... like for monkeys.
About the tools, I believe that something like a `Github Wiki` would work fine, but (1) we are not on `Github` and (2) wouldn't be `LaTeX` a better way of writing stuff in order to publicise it, eventually. I know we can get our `Markdown` rendered in a printable way with http://www.cocowrite.com/, but is it the most efficient solution? `LaTeX` would be a nuisance for collaborative editing and online `HTML` publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer can be found [here: “What tools are used to write documentation?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537/what-tools-are-used-to-write-documentation).
Second part of the answer can be found [here: “What amount of documentation is needed for a non-trivial one-man software project”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740245/what-amount-of-documentation-is-needed-for-a-non-trivial-one-man-software-projec)